# Can you automate change of settings for all phones?

Tags: voip, asterisk

Is it possible to automate the process of changing some settings for VOIP phones running on Asterisk PBX?

i.e. I have 10 phones connecting to PBX at all time. 5 of those phones are at one customer location, other 5 at another customer. Let's say I want to change the Server address for all those phones from my computer that has access to PBX admin panel.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give us details on your environment such as whether or not your using an interface for Asterisk such as FreePBX.  It would also be helpful to know what brand and model of phones you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you calls support ***PROVISION***

Check about that in your phone's manual